# Getting device's country code/phone number

Tags: android, phone-number, country-codes, mobile-country-code

How can my app programmatically obtain the device's country/area code?

When I receive an incoming SMS, the sender number always includes the country/area code. However, for my app, I'm letting the user manually enter his/her phone number, but I need to also know the country/area code.

Is there anyway to obtain the device's country code and/or phone number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you mean

1- Add This Array to Strings.xml File

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
<item>93,AF</item>
<item>355,AL</item>
<item>213,DZ</item>
<item>376,AD</item>
<item>244,AO</item>
<item>672,AQ</item>
<item>54,AR</item>
<item>374,AM</item>
<item>297,AW</item>
<item>61,AU</item>
<item>43,AT</item>
<item>994,AZ</item>
<item>973,BH</item>
<item>880,BD</item>
<item>375,BY</item>
<item>32,BE</item>
<item>501,BZ</item>
<item>229,BJ</item>
<item>975,BT</item>
<item>591,BO</item>
<item>387,BA</item>
<item>267,BW</item>
<item>55,BR</item>
<item>673,BN</item>
<item>359,BG</item>
<item>226,BF</item>
<item>95,MM</item>
<item>257,BI</item>
<item>855,KH</item>
<item>237,CM</item>
<item>1,CA</item>
<item>238,CV</item>
<item>236,CF</item>
<item>235,TD</item>
<item>56,CL</item>
<item>86,CN</item>
<item>61,CX</item>
<item>61,CC</item>
<item>57,CO</item>
<item>269,KM</item>
<item>242,CG</item>
<item>243,CD</item>
<item>682,CK</item>
<item>506,CR</item>
<item>385,HR</item>
<item>53,CU</item>
<item>357,CY</item>
<item>420,CZ</item>
<item>45,DK</item>
<item>253,DJ</item>
<item>670,TL</item>
<item>593,EC</item>
<item>20,EG</item>
<item>503,SV</item>
<item>240,GQ</item>
<item>291,ER</item>
<item>372,EE</item>
<item>251,ET</item>
<item>500,FK</item>
<item>298,FO</item>
<item>679,FJ</item>
<item>358,FI</item>
<item>33,FR</item>
<item>689,PF</item>
<item>241,GA</item>
<item>220,GM</item>
<item>995,GE</item>
<item>49,DE</item>
<item>233,GH</item>
<item>350,GI</item>
<item>30,GR</item>
<item>299,GL</item>
<item>502,GT</item>
<item>224,GN</item>
<item>245,GW</item>
<item>592,GY</item>
<item>509,HT</item>
<item>504,HN</item>
<item>852,HK</item>
<item>36,HU</item>
<item>91,IN</item>
<item>62,ID</item>
<item>98,IR</item>
<item>964,IQ</item>
<item>353,IE</item>
<item>44,IM</item>
<item>972,IL</item>
<item>39,IT</item>
<item>225,CI</item>
<item>81,JP</item>
<item>962,JO</item>
<item>7,KZ</item>
<item>254,KE</item>
<item>686,KI</item>
<item>965,KW</item>
<item>996,KG</item>
<item>856,LA</item>
<item>371,LV</item>
<item>961,LB</item>
<item>266,LS</item>
<item>231,LR</item>
<item>218,LY</item>
<item>423,LI</item>
<item>370,LT</item>
<item>352,LU</item>
<item>853,MO</item>
<item>389,MK</item>
<item>261,MG</item>
<item>265,MW</item>
<item>60,MY</item>
<item>960,MV</item>
<item>223,ML</item>
<item>356,MT</item>
<item>692,MH</item>
<item>222,MR</item>
<item>230,MU</item>
<item>262,YT</item>
<item>52,MX</item>
<item>691,FM</item>
<item>373,MD</item>
<item>377,MC</item>
<item>976,MN</item>
<item>382,ME</item>
<item>212,MA</item>
<item>258,MZ</item>
<item>264,NA</item>
<item>674,NR</item>
<item>977,NP</item>
<item>31,NL</item>
<item>599,AN</item>
<item>687,NC</item>
<item>64,NZ</item>
<item>505,NI</item>
<item>227,NE</item>
<item>234,NG</item>
<item>683,NU</item>
<item>850,KP</item>
<item>47,NO</item>
<item>968,OM</item>
<item>92,PK</item>
<item>680,PW</item>
<item>507,PA</item>
<item>675,PG</item>
<item>595,PY</item>
<item>51,PE</item>
<item>63,PH</item>
<item>870,PN</item>
<item>48,PL</item>
<item>351,PT</item>
<item>1,PR</item>
<item>974,QA</item>
<item>40,RO</item>
<item>7,RU</item>
<item>250,RW</item>
<item>590,BL</item>
<item>685,WS</item>
<item>378,SM</item>
<item>239,ST</item>
<item>966,SA</item>
<item>221,SN</item>
<item>381,RS</item>
<item>248,SC</item>
<item>232,SL</item>
<item>65,SG</item>
<item>421,SK</item>
<item>386,SI</item>
<item>677,SB</item>
<item>252,SO</item>
<item>27,ZA</item>
<item>82,KR</item>
<item>34,ES</item>
<item>94,LK</item>
<item>290,SH</item>
<item>508,PM</item>
<item>249,SD</item>
<item>597,SR</item>
<item>268,SZ</item>
<item>46,SE</item>
<item>41,CH</item>
<item>963,SY</item>
<item>886,TW</item>
<item>992,TJ</item>
<item>255,TZ</item>
<item>66,TH</item>
<item>228,TG</item>
<item>690,TK</item>
<item>676,TO</item>
<item>216,TN</item>
<item>90,TR</item>
<item>993,TM</item>
<item>688,TV</item>
<item>971,AE</item>
<item>256,UG</item>
<item>44,GB</item>
<item>380,UA</item>
<item>598,UY</item>
<item>1,US</item>
<item>998,UZ</item>
<item>678,VU</item>
<item>39,VA</item>
<item>58,VE</item>
<item>84,VN</item>
<item>681,WF</item>
<item>967,YE</item>
<item>260,ZM</item>
<item>263,ZW</item>
```

2-CopyThis Function To your Class

```
String GetCountryZipCode(){

    String CountryID="";
    String CountryZipCode="";

   TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          //getNetworkCountryIso
    CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    String[] rl=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    for(int i=0;i<rl.length;i++){
                                String[] g=rl[i].split(",");
                                if(g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
                                                    CountryZipCode=g[0];break;  }
    }
```

If you want country code stored in your sim card then try this:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
```

OR

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
locale.getCountry();
```

Comment: +1 for showing that it is possible in multiple ways!

Answer (score 3):

You can use TelephonyManager. This is an example :

```
String iso = null ;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// Get network country iso
        if (telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso() != null
                && !telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().toString().equals(""))
        {
            iso = telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().toString();
        }
```